# How to detect if HPET is available

Tags: c++, winapi

how can I detect (using C++) wether my system has a HPET or not?

Thx for your help,
Tobias

---

HPET = [High Precision Event Timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer)

Comment: What is HPET?  Could you examine the registry or *Program Files/HPET*?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607263/how-precise-is-the-internal-clock-of-a-modern-pc/2615977#2615977

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system has a HPET, then it should be listed in the device manager and therefore somewhere in the registry. I would see if there is a key in there somewhere that denotes a HPET. I'm not in win32 right now, but msdn mentions HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\Active.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447470.aspx