# std::chrono::duration_cast - any unit more precise than nano-second?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I wanted to ask that how can I calculate time in any units like picosecond, femtosecond and up to  more precision. I am calculating running times for functions and using nanoseconds, the running time of functions is returning 0 when i use millisecond or nanosecond. I think Chrono library supports only till nanosecond, It was the most precise which appeared when I pressed ctrl+space after typing chrono::

```
int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "f() took "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count()
              << " milliseconds\n";
}
```

code source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast

Thanks.

Comment: try running each function 1000 times or more, then divide the result time by 1000. Also note that maximum precision on windows is 1 - 15 ms, depending if your windows likes you or not

Comment: @TheOne what if running the function 1000 times takes 10 microseconds, i.e. 0.01 milliseconds in that clock with 1 millisecond of precision?

Comment: @TheOne, this is not true. Windows has high resolution timers that have 100 nanosecond precision. You have to use the Windows API to get at them, but they are there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: <chrono> in Visual Studio not only has a really poor high-resolution clock, but it also has broken duration mixed arithmetic (that flat-out doesn't work ever and thus was obviously never tested; and for some reason the thingy costs up to $14k). I recommend resorting to Boost.Chrono if you have to use Visual Studio.

Comment: I have to submit the assignment, will the teacher pc also need to have boost library installed/set-up as it is external library.

Comment: @syazdani well yea that is true, you can also use __rdtsc() with visual studio and you are totally right, but std::chrono has maximum precision of 1 ms in Visual Studio(the same as clock())

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can calculate time in more precise durations (picoseconds...)

[www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html)

See the following definition:

```
typedef ratio<1, 1000000000000> pico;
```

then use:

```
duration<double, pico> d{1.23}; //...1.23 picoseconds
```

UPDATE
Your question has three parts:

1. How to use std::chrono and make calculation with std::chrono::duration
2. How to get higher precision timestamps
3. How to do performance mesurments of your code

Above I partially answered only for the first question (how to define "picoseconds" duration). Consider the following code as example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void f()
{
    enum { max_count = 10000 };
    cout << '|';
    for(volatile size_t count = 0; count != max_count; ++count)
    {
        if(!(count % (max_count / 10)))
            cout << '.';
    }
    cout << "|\n";
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::ratio<1l, 1000000000000l> pico;
    typedef duration<long long, pico> picoseconds;
    typedef std::ratio<1l, 1000000l> micro;
    typedef duration<long long, micro> microseconds;

    const auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    enum { number_of_test_cycles = 10 };
    for(size_t count = 0; count != number_of_test_cycles; ++count)
    {
        f();
    }
    const auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << number_of_test_cycles << " times f() took:\n"
         << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " milliseconds\n"
         << duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " microseconds\n"
         << duration_cast<picoseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " picoseconds\n";
}
```

It produces this output:

```
$ ./test
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
10 times f() took:
1 milliseconds
1084 microseconds
1084000000 picoseconds
```

As you see in order to get 1 millisecond result I had to repeat f() 10 times. Repeating your test is general approach when your timer doesn't have enough precision. There is one problem associated with repetition - it's not neccessary that repeating your test N times takes proportianal period of time. You need to prove it first.

Another thing - although I can make calculation using picoseconds durations my high_resolution_timer can't give me higher precision than microseconds.

To get higher precision you can use timestamp counter, see [wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) - but this is tricky and platform specific.

Comment: How will I use this to replicate the functionality in the code I have posted in question, Can you please point in the code which I have posted, how to change it so that it uses the method you have described. Regards

Answer (score 6):

A "standard" PC has a resolution of around 100 nanoseconds, so trying to measure time at resolutions greater than that is not really possible unless you have custom hardware of some kind. See [How precise is the internal clock of a modern PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607263/how-precise-is-the-internal-clock-of-a-modern-pc) for a related question and check out the second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615977/1169863.

Comment: This may be so but that is not the point. Sometimes you have to do calculations with time and you want to minimise the effect of roundoff errors. So  the calculations are done at a much higher precision than your clock supports.