# Accurate System time

Tags: java, systemtime

What is the best way to get the most accurate system time (hours minutes and seconds) correct upto milliseconds in java. I have been looking into Clock, Date and Calendar objects. I want to be able to timestamp a packet with the most accurate System time and send it over the network(accurate to Milli or even NanoSeconds if possible).

Comment: The accuracy of the system clock depends on the system, not Java - the best you can hope for on most platforms is 15 milliseconds or so. `Instant.now()` will give you the current time.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I did look at Instant.now() aswell but it is giving me accuracy up only till three decimal places. If I use the calendar object and call the getTimeInMillis() on it it gives me a lot more accuracy. So I am confused.

Comment: Three decimal places of _what_? `Instant` [has nanos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getNano--). But as I said above, what units a particular timestamp is in is completely irrelevant, your OS is likely recording in 10's of milliseconds so whether your timestamp is in milli/micro/nano/pico seconds has no meaning.

Comment: @BoristheSpider This is what it reads. "2016-06-29T17:54:32.919Z" So thats 3 decimals off the seconds counter. Also this is UTC I am guessing I couldnt see a method to get localtime. Also Is there anyway to just snapshot this time so I can save it and perform operations on this time object?

Comment: How does the default `String` representation of an `Instant` affect anything? You could also format it to only have a year. Please **please** PLEASE read at least one tutorial before posting further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Java 9

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework supports values with up to [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. That means up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction of second.

In [Java 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later, a new implementation of [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) can capture the current moment up to that [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. But “your mileage may vary”. The actual resolution, and the actual accuracy, depend on the host hardware clock capability.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

> 2016-01-02T12:34:56.123456789Z

## Java 8

Same as for Java 9, java.time classes support up to [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution.

But the current moment is captured only up to [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution. That means only three (3) or fewer digits of fractional second. This limit is because of a legacy implementation used for `Clock`.

## Java 6 & 7

The old date-time classes first  bundled with the earliest versions of Java support only milliseconds resolution. This includes `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.util.GregorianCalendar`. These old classes are also poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. Avoid them.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

As far as I know these rely upon the same legacy implementation, for only milliseconds resolution.

## Accuracy

[Accuracy and precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) always depends on your host hardware clock capability.

See the Question, [How precise is the internal clock of a modern PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2607263/642706)

As I understand today’s common computer hardware, you cannot expect the current moment will be captured with single nanosecond precision.

Comment: Excellent summary. The main thing is that the system clock resolution is likely lower than a nanosecond.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that explanation. Its too bad that it captures only a millisecond resolution. This is a part of a small API that I am working on and I essentially require that precision. Sadly java spoils the deal for me.

Comment: @Krish If capturing current moment in finer than milliseconds is really that important, then consider pulling the `Clock` implementation from Java 9 pre-release code into your own app with your own `Clock` class. (If you can abide by its GPL license.) I don't know what is involved; you'll have to browse the OpenJDK source code. Note how the java.time classes allow for injecting a `Clock` object. [`Instant.now( Clock clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-java.time.Clock-)

Comment: @Krish Another possibility is to call out to native code to access a platform-specific library to get the current moment from host OS. There are a few ways to call native code from Java, with JNI being one though I believe there is a newer easier way (don't know details).

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for that. I was actually just looking into JNI. But I guess its probably not a bad idea to look at the java 9 pre-release. Thanks for that. Extremely appreciate the help.

Comment: @Krish FYI… [Java Native Access(JNA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) is the easier alternative to JNI. (Not that I've ever used either.) Also, you could combine these ideas, to make a `Clock` implementation that wraps calls to the native code call to the host OS clock library. Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to get time in nano seconds means then use
**system.nanoTime();** this would be the best

Comment: No. As explained in the documentation; `nanoTime` is nanos elapsed since JVM start.