# accuracy of datetime module

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, random

I'm trying to write a code to execute a print function at a specific local time in microsecond resolution. I'm using python 3.6. My simple code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
while True:
    now=datetime.now()
    now=(now.hour,now.minute,now.second,now.microsecond)
    if now>(0,42,40,0):
        print(now)
        break
```

these are some results:
 for time (0,42,40,0) result is:(0, 42, 40, 255)
 for time (0,49,0,0) result is:(0, 49, 0, 841)
 for time (0,51,0,0) result is (0, 51, 30, 86). 
the problem is every time i run this code this code starts at different times with a random distribution in microseconds while I need the delay to be constant in 1 microsecond accuracy.
my OS is Windows 10.
I'll be appreciate if anybody helps me to solve this problem.
thanks.

Comment: Depending on the implementation and OS, the accuracy of time can be of different accuracies. For example on my (mac) computer it is accurate to about 10 microseconds.

Comment: thank you Eric, actually I ran this coed on Ubuntu OS too and it didn't change too much.

Comment: may be of interest although not python-specific: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2607263/10197418 - and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938048/high-precision-clock-in-python